# Recover single asset history

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to recover the history of a single asset. The model is defined like the following

```
namespace org.example.basic

asset SampleAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  --> SampleParticipant owner
  o String value
}

participant SampleParticipant identified by participantId {
  o String participantId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

transaction GetAssetHistory {
    o String assetId
}

event SampleEvent {
  --> SampleAsset asset
  o String oldValue
  o String newValue
}
```

I generate a single participant and a new asset referencing to the previous participant. And I proceed to update the asset value variable value. But reading about asset update I found the following:

```
async function getAssetHistory(tx) {
    //How can I get a single asset history using the tx.assetId value??
    let historian = await businessNetworkConnection.getHistorian();
    let historianRecords = historian.getAll();
    console.log(prettyoutput(historianRecords));
}
```

When I deploy the bna and I call the function I get the following:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGU0Z.jpg)
In other functions i use the RuntimeApi but I dont know if businessNetworkConnection is a Runtime API call.

Any idea of how can a get a single asset history?
Any example on internet?

***************** UPDATE

I change the way to recover a particula asset history. Doing the following:
In js file

```
/**
 * Sample read-only transaction
 * @param {org.example.trading.MyPartHistory} tx
 * @returns {org.example.trading.Trader[]} All trxns  
 * @transaction
 */
async function participantHistory(tx) {
    console.log('1');
    const partId = tx.tradeid;
    console.log('2');
    const nativeSupport = tx.nativeSupport;
    // const partRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.example.trading.Trader')
    console.log('3');
    const nativeKey = getNativeAPI().createCompositeKey('Asset:org.example.trading.Trader', [partId]);
    console.log('4');
    const iterator = await getNativeAPI().getHistoryForKey(nativeKey);
    let results = [];
    let res = {done : false};
    while (!res.done) {
        res = await iterator.next();

        if (res && res.value && res.value.value) {
            let val = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
            if (val.length > 0) {
               console.log("@debug val is  " + val );
               results.push(JSON.parse(val));
            }
        }
        if (res && res.done) {
            try {
                iterator.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
            }
        }
    }
    var newArray = [];
    for (const item of results) {
            newArray.push(getSerializer().fromJSON(item));
    }
    console.log("@debug the results to be returned are as follows: ");

    return newArray; // returns something to my NodeJS client (called via REST API)
 }
```

In model file

```
@commit(false)
@returns(Trader[])
transaction MyPartHistory {
    o String tradeId
}
```

I create a single asset an di update then with other values. But whe I call the MyPartHistory i get the following message:

> Error: Native API not available in web runtime

Answer (score 0):

use of the native api is only available when you are running your business network in a real fabric environment. You can't use it in the online playground environment. You will have to setup a real fabric environment and then run playground locally connecting to that fabric in order to test your business network.